# Присвоение автомобилю оценки на основании его характеристик

Tags: алгоритм, javascript, нейронные-сети

В общем, не хочу изобретать велосипед (да и это не лучшим образом получится). Я использую JavaScript и хочу сделать это на WEB странице но суть не в том, нужен лучший метод оценки (наиболее правдоподобные оценки на выходе):
Я играю игру Real Racing и чтобы решить какую машину лучше выбрать я решил сделать следующее:

Выписать характеристики автомобилей (буду называть автомобили `A1` `A2` и т.д):

1. Имя n (name)
2. Максимальная скорость `m` (maxSpeed) [км/ч] Больше - лучше
3. Разгон от 0 до 100 `b` (boost) [сек] Меньше - лучше
4. Тормозной путь `d` (brakingDistance) [м] Меньше- лучше
5. Сцепление `с` (coupling) [g] Больше - лучше

Вот пример:

```
1. A1 {
  - n = Ford Focus RS
  - m = 262
  - b = 5.9
  - d = 38.7
  - c = 0.94
 }

 2. A2 {
  - n = Ford Shelby GT 500
  - m = 289
  - b = 4.1
  - d = 32.6
  - c = 0.92
 }

 3. A3 {
  - n = Audi TT RS Coupe 
  - m = 249
  - b = 4.0
  - d = 36.8
  - c = 0.89
 }
```

Допустим у меня есть массив заполненный характеристиками, так что:

```
A[1].m = 262;
A[3].c = 0.89;
```

И я хочу сравнить все характеристики всех машин и каждой выставить одну оценку (может у нескольких машин будет одна оценка) но чтобы машина с большей оценкой - имела лучшие характеристики (усреднённо учитывая все 4 (`m` `b` `d` `c`) характеристики) чем машина с меньшей. 
Мне даже на глаз сложно выставить оценки у `3` приведенных авто но я думаю может такую задачи под силу решить алгоритму. Например такие оценки:

```
A1.mark = 3
A2.mark = 1
A3.mark = 2
```

В результате загнав все характеристики всех машин и их имена хочу получить что то типа:

```
|Машина (#id)       |Оценка:|
-----------------------------
|Aston Martin (A9)  |  19   |
 ----------------------------
|Ferrari Enzo (A15) |  28   |
  ---------------------------
|Nissan Sumo P (A22)|  19   |
-----------------------------
|Ford Focus RS (A51)|  10   |
```

Тогда если в игре у меня выбор что купить:
`A51` или `A15` => я посмотрю на оценки и выберу `A51`. (Меньше - лучше)
`A9` или `A22` => я посмотрю на оценки увижу что они одинаковы и сам выберу `A9` 
Как всё заполнить и вывести я знаю а вот как выставить оценку вот в этом вопрос
 Вообще такое возможно реализовать? Может есть готовые алгоритмы, или это так сложно что лучше даже не начинать? :)

*PS:* В математике я `0`, в олимпиадных задачах тоже.
*PPS:* За то знаю JS и (надеюсь) смогу реализовать готовый алгоритм:)

***UPD***: Придумал такое:
 Возьмём к примеру `A1` `A2` `A3` которые я привёл.

```
   | m˄ | b˅ |  d˅ | c˄  |
 -------------------------
A1 |262 |5.9 |38.7 |0.94 |
 -------------------------
A2 |289 |4.1 |32.6 |0.92 |
 -------------------------
A3 |249 |4.0 |36.8 |0.89 |
```

1) по `m` установим оценку для машин (от `1` до количества машин (`3`)):

```
A1 = 2; A2 = 1; A3 = 3;
```

так же и по `b`, `d`, `c`, для каждой машины, учитывая для каждой характеристики меньше -    лучше (`˅`) или больше - лучше (`˄`) (смотреть выше) итоговая оценка (от `1` до `3`  меньше - лучше):

```
   |    Оценки:        |
------------------------
id | m˅ | b˅ | d˅ | c˅ |
------------------------
A1 | 2  | 3  | 3  | 1  |
------------------------
A2 | 1  | 2  | 1  | 2  |
------------------------
A3 | 3  | 1  | 2  | 3  |
```

2) Теперь, имея для `A1` `2`, `3`, `3`, `1` вычисляем среднюю оценку = `(2+3+3+1)/4=2.25`
  И для всех машин среднюю оценку:

```
|Машина|Средняя оценка(˅):|
---------------------------
|A1    |   2.25           |
---------------------------
|A2    |   1.5            |
---------------------------
|A3    |   2.25           |
```

Теперь (т.к я хочу оценку цело число):
 У `A2` оценка `= 1` а у `A1` и `A3` оценка `=` `2` (средняя оценка - меньше - лучше (˅))
 Но наверное этот метод - велосипед с квадратными колёсами. Как вам этот метод? Если плох  то предложите что то лучшее...

***UPD2***: Мне надо возможно доделать:
Ускорение(`b`) имеет высший приоритет(допустим `1.0`), сцепление (`c`) меньший (скажем `0.8` ), тормозной путь (`d`) еще меньший (`0.7`) макс скорость (`m`) самый малый приоритет (`0.6`). Как бы мне это применить

***UPD3***: Вот облом, я столько думал над этим а в игре всё это время был и есть "РП" - Рейтинг Производительности, и он у: A1=4.6 A2=27.5  A3=18.8 :) и не как у меня A1 = A3 а РП совсем не равен :). Интересно конечно как они это сделали но я уж лучше воспользуюсь готовым. Я принимаю ответ жду ещё комментов и закрываю вопрос, всем спасибо!

Comment: а выбор машины от трассы зависит ? так-то просто берем весь набор машин, считаем среднее арифметическое по каждому параметру - это 0, максимальное отклонение от среднего - 5 балов например (плюс и минус) считаем отклонение для каждой машины, интерполируем на эту десятибальную шкалу. складываем все баллы. если какие-то характеристики более важные, перед сложением умножаем их на коэффициент важности (1.1 например или 1.5)

Comment: @eicto
>>  интерполируем на эту десятибальную шкалу
Мне это ни о чём не говорит :( можно для более необразованных. Как вам мой подход (см. UPD)?

Comment: Наверное стоит учитывать саму трассу. Если на трассе много поворотов, то главное в машине - ускорение, если трасса с длинными прямыми участками - то максимальная скорость. Следует также выбирать, какие повороты присутствует на трассе. Если они не сильно резкие, то стоит выбрать машину с плохим управлением, но более сильным мотором. А так самое простое - это среднее арифметическое... http://jsfiddle.net/tpL6S/1/

Comment: @lampa - ваш метод не правилен (мне кажется) хотя бы потому что (как я указал) m и c - больше - лучше а b и d - меньше лучше и оценка должна быть относительно всех машин как в предложенном мною методе.  
+Мне так глубоко продумывать не надо. (Машину выбрать нужно для СЕРИИ гонок а в ней 5 машин на выбор и разные трассы денег лишь на одну машину хватит) Что мне надо так это: Ускорение(`b`) имеет высший приоритет(допустим 1.0), сцепление (c) меньший (скажем 0.8 ), тормозной путь (d) еще меньший (0.7) макс скорость (m) самый малый приоритет (0.6). Как бы мне это применить к моему ***UPD1***?

Comment: Помогите кто нибудь вообще сделать адекватную оценку характеристик авто если не учитывать характеристику трассы а просто автомобилям из списка каждому выставить оценку на основании характеристик желательно чтобы оценка была целое число меньше- лучше машина с оценкой 1 из 279 лучшая из данных 279, если у двух машин оценка 200 - надо подумать самому какая лучше а машина с оценкой 279 - худшая однозначно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Rules ну, тогда как посоветовал @eicto добавьте баллы и умножайте их на коэф важности:

[image]

Думаю на картинке всё понятно.

Comment: Спасибо! Все бы так отвечали :) (holly dream).Ответ пока не приму , буду разбираться и может кто то что то еще подскажет...  
PS: Кстати машин будет около 250 штук, данный метод будет с таким количеством работать?

Comment: А как вам мой метод?

Comment: @Rules да данный метод и с миллионом отработает.. А ваш метод тоже ведь основан на коэф, так чем они отличаются? Выбирать между n-ыми машинами, чей рейтинг максимален и одинаков - лучше уже самому.

Comment: @lampa, посмотрите ***UPD3***...